# JSF two-colum repeatable table inside panelgrid or equivalent

Tags: jsf

I have List of items that needs to be displayed as a table. That table need to be repeated as a two-column grid where each cell contains the same table side by side where the right side is a continuation of the right side table, like so:

```
a|b|c  a|b|c
-+-+-  -+-+-
1|2|3  5|6|7
x|y|z  n|m|o
.....  .....
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which components libraries are you using? Richfaces, Tomahawk, Icefaces... ?

Comment: I fixed the formatting. It was not clear at first because it was not preformatted. Can you please confirm if I guessed it right? Also, please mention the JSF impl/version used and also if you're using JSP or Facelets as view technology. Also, it would help a lot if you add the `List<Item>` object to start with and the "raw" HTML code of how the final result should look like (e.g. `<table><tr><td><ul><li>` and so on). Right now I can't get the functional requirement right. It's too vague and ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make your managed bean return list of lists and use `<ui:repeat>` and `<h:dataTable>`. Each of your internal list is for one table, and contains table rows.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.tablesLists}" var="tableList">
  <h:dataTable var="tableRow" value="#{tableList}">
    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="a" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.data1}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="b" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.data2}" />
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not considering facelet before this post but find it to be my last avenue. I am able to do it with just the one list.